# Creating Registry Using Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, regedit

I am working on creating a batch file that adds will create registry entries in order to add custom commands into the UI of our file management software.

The issue is that the location of the key varies based on the version of the software a user is on.

Is it possible to create a patch file that will search within registry keys/sub keys and create new values there?

Here is an example of the registry location, the portion surrounded by ** will change based on version:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Motive\M-Files\**12.0.6550.8**\Client\MFShell\Rombald\TasksBar\ShellCommands\1]
"Name"="Calendar"
"Executable"="\\\\mfiles-server\\M-Files setup\\M-Files 
Calendar\\MFCalendar_v1.2.6\\MFCalendar_v1.2.6\\M-Files Calendar.exe"
"Icon"="\\\\mfiles-server\\M-Files setup\\M-Files 
Calendar\\MFCalendar_v1.2.6\\MFCalendar_v1.2.6\\M-Files Calendar.exe,0"
"Arguments"="{B1438CAB-2E53-474E-AA82-3D48F787F6B7}"
```

Essentially I would have to look for the version of the software and insert that into the key. If more than one exists it would be the largest value.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I can't find any * in your sample. And how could the version of that software be retrieved? Is there a command line switch like `-v` that prints it to the console?

Comment: My apologies, added the *.

The version could be retrieved from the Program file path (example below).

    C:\Program Files\M-Files\12.0.6400.37

I am not aware of a command line switch that would do so.

Comment: See `Reg.exe /?`

Comment: @LotPings
Running reg.exe was my plan, jsut trying to get it into the correct location as the version may vary on some workstations.

Comment: The functionality of reg.exe didn't change for some time/versions - so that isn't an issue

Comment: The version of the software varies per workstations and the location of the registry key will vary based on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'reg query HKCU\SOFTWARE\Motive\M-Files'
) do set "root=%%~A" & set "version=%%~nxA"

echo root: %root%
echo version: %version%

if defined root (
    echo Write new reg information.
    reg add "%root%\testkey" /v testvalue /d data /f
    reg add "%root%\testkey" /v testversion /d "%version%" /f
)
```

The `for` loop uses the command `reg query` to search through
the entries in the registry key. The last entry is saved as
`root` and `version`. The variable `root` will have the full key path
while the variable `version` will be the last segment of the path
which will be just the key name. These are echoed to console.

If defined root, subkey `testkey` will be added with values and
data as the code shows.

So long as you only have version keys under the key of `M-Files`
then this may be all you may need. If not, then you may need more
code to skip the other keys.

Comment: I'll have to look to see if other software has versions but this should be more than enough to get me started, thanks a lot!